# How to create the perfect background image

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, background-image, fixed

I have a background image that I want to use on a webpage. I will probably use CSS. The background image will contain a person in the background that will be to the left of other content (like a voting box, fans listing, etc). How do I go about it so the bg picture shows perfectly regardless of the resolution of the computer, the size of the window, and browser used, etc.

Comment: for perfect resolution start coding already

Comment: What do you mean by show perfectly? If you mean it always has to be left of the content in the same vertical position you need to use a wrapper div around the content that will contain the background image.

Answer (score 2):

There's an updated version of bgStretcher, [bgStretcher II](http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-2-jquery-stretch-background-plugin-updated.html).

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a bit of [jQuery](http://jquery.com), here is [the plugin to stretch the background proportionally.](http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-jquery-stretch-background-plugin.html).